# Laravel 5 post tag relation

Tags: laravel

I'm trying to create post-tag relationship. I stuck when it's updating. I have input in edit page. how can I handle tag relation ?. I tried

```
$project->tags()->sync(explode(",",$request->tag));
```

But I guess I have to send tag's id to sync ? How can I do? Thanks..

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like `$request->tag` has tag names in it, like "tag1,tag2,tag3". In this case, you'll need to get IDs for these tags first:

```
$tagIds = Tag::whereIn('name', explode(',', $request->tag))->pluck('id')->toArray();
```

And then use `sync()` with this IDs array:

```
$project->tags()->sync($tagIds);
```

Comment: and also i need to check if tag is exist ? ı,

Comment: @MuzafferŞenkal if you're talking about avoiding errors, then don't worry. This code will just skip any tags you don't have in `tags` directory. If you want to add new tags, just do this before executing the code from the answer.